# How can be dynamic this query of npoco

Tags: c#, npoco

Instead of the adding search method to every class like this;

```
    public List<InvoiceDetail> SearchById(int Id)
    {
        return db.Query<InvoiceDetail>()
            .Where(x => x.Id == Id)
            .ToList();
    }
```

How to add a method to base class like this;

```
    public virtual List<T> SearchById(int Id)
    {
        return db.Query<T>()
           .Where(x => x.Id == Id)
           .ToList();
    }
```

"T does not contain a definition for Id"

Because Id is the definition of Detail entities.

Comment: See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters - can you add a base class/interface constraint on allowed type of T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a base class as:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then make the appropriate entity classes inherit from `BaseEntity` as:

```
public class Detail : BaseEntity
{
   //some props for Detail class only
}
```

Now for your search method you can use the `where T : class` constrain as:

```
public List<T> SearchById<T>(int id) where T : BaseEntity
{
   return db.Query<T>()
       .Where(x => x.Id == Id)
       .ToList();
}
```